# Facebook OAuth dialog failed to load on iOS 6 with "Too many HTTP directs"

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth

We have a strange issue in our app.

Our app is semi native/semi HTML iOS app.
We were using the standard Facebook OAuth dialog to allow users to log in into our app using their Facebook crentials.
However, recently (I think probably after upgrade to iOS 6.0.1, but cannot be sure) we started getting the error "Too many HTTP redirects" when trying to load a request in UIWebView, which points to https://m.facebook.com/dialog/OAuth

The strange thing is - it works in iOS Simulator for iOS 6.0, but doesn't work on a real device (iPhone 4S with iOS 6.0.1). I was unable to verify that yet on a device with an older version of iOS (6.0 or 5.x)

Did probably anyone experienced a similar issue and is the any way to overcome it?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: I'm getting this as well. We're looking into it and I'll post back if we find anything.

Comment: @James: It looks like the Facebook had fixed that already. I don't have a problem for about a week or so.